# Testing UIButton triggers IBAction Listener UI Automation testing Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.2

I am trying to Test my app using Xcode 7 UI tests automation but I am having issue in button tap. I need to know if there exists any way to check if button tapped has triggered the IBAction Listener.
Currently my test case is succeeding but in actual the button listener is not getting triggered.

```
app.buttons["Liquor"].tap()
```

Comment: This sounds like something is missing from your production app. You will have to post more code for any help.

Comment: This is a unit test and you can code any check you want. If you are looking for a test that says, did the action get called from the tap, how would it know which action to check? And if the answer is that it should check the action to which it is linked, then the test has no purpose. If the link is there then it will get called.  So what are you really testing? As a simple suggestion, add a variable that gets a new value in your function and in the test, check the value before and after the tap.